# Accessing a url directly without login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I am considering doing this -

Any url (excecpt those I disallow specifically) can be accessed directly without signing-in, however if you click on any of the links on the page, it will redirect you to the sign-up page

I am thinking of several ways of doing it, but neither is flexible enough to work with devise

1. Create a new `link_to_not_registered` helper which I will use on every `link_to` and it will check if the user is logged in or not
2. create a before_filter to check if the user is logged in. This is a bit problematic, as I don't know how to create a filter only when linking and not when directly accessing a page
3. Have an external flag to test if the user is logged in and change the page accordingly.

neither way helps me redirect the user after sign-in/sign up (new helper links to sign up, before filter becomes too complex, flags are too simple)

```
Is there a way to create a functionality of direct access to show actions while clicking on links requires login?
```

Comment: One option springs to mind: set a session variable, if user tries to access another page, redirect to sign-up page. I wouldn't advise you replace link_to. Also, your `before_filter` idea would work if you ensured the referrer was from your application.

Comment: how would a session variable help in this situation? just check its existence?

Comment: It comes down to the reasoning behind this behavior. Is it so you can give guests limited access to your site? If so, a session variable might work. You could even have a ticker with a page view limit before the user is asked to sign-up.

Comment: Hmm..however, if you simply must mask all links, there is no other way than using a different `link_to` method or rendering a different template. Anything beyond that, the user will be able to view the links. The user will be able to access them directly, or delete their session. It depends how robust this solution must be. Seems you'd be over-engineering a solution for users who want to exploit the workings of your site. Normal users would be unaffected, and see the sign-up page.

Comment: what about creating a session variable once entering a page. And in a before_filter checking if that session variable exists. If it does, then this isn't the first page, so sign-in is needed.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but it doesn't mask your links. The only way to bypass that would be to copy-paste direct urls from links, and delete session. You'll still have to be a bit creative in the `before_filter` to ensure you delete it when a user registers/signs in.

Comment: Another way to do this, without masking links pre-render, is to mask them post-render with javascript? -- might need to be smart with the selector -- `$('#content a').attr('href', 'sing_up_path')`. In fact, if you used all 3, to bypass the user would then have to disable javascript, delete session, and copy-paste direct urls. At least all this avoids overwriting or extending `link_to`.

Comment: you should use cancan.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is a before_filter. You can check previous page by request.referrer, so if it's a page inside your app, you redirect user to signin path

```
def to_signin
    redirect_to singin_path if request.referrer["http://myapp.com"]
end
```